# Google Script: autoResizeColumn not working properly on hyperlink

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

recently I've been working on Google spreadsheet using the incorporated script editor.
I've a bunch of columns with some data retrieved automatically from a web request.

One of this column has all hyperlink of different lengths plus a simple header. 
When I try to perform the method

```
ss.autoResizeColumn(2);
```

the execution of autoResizeColumn seems to use as reference the header value.

When executing the automatic resize manually to other columns without hyperlinks all works just fine. 
Doing this operation directly using the sheet, the hyperlinks column is being resized correctly .

The header is insert with this command:

```
ss.getRange(3,2).setValue("header").setFontSize(20).setFontWeight("bold");
```

and the hyperlinks with this command:

```
ss.getRange(row,column).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("url";"text")');
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you need to run [`flush`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush) before resizing columns:

```
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  ss.autoResizeColumn(2);
```

Comment: I added `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` before `ss.autoResizeColumn(2);` and it worked. However the width is wrongly adapted. Doing it manually the width perfectly fit the hyperlink width. Doing it automatically the width is too much (another 8 characters fit the remaining space)

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Could you please, share your sample?

Comment: `function myFunction() {
  var ID = "1tvrwtlsPuLG5l58VjrBiNzT0yWMzlD_8wDP9Xe0QDNw";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ID).getSheetByName("Foglio1");
  for (i=2;i<20;i++)  ss.getRange(i,2).setFormula('=HYPERLINK("LINK";"AAAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaAAAAAAA")');
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  ss.autoResizeColumn(2);
}
`
where ID is your sheet ID

Comment: I can't find out, why, but with long strings `autoResizeColumn` works incorrectly. I've tried just entering value: `setValue("AAAAAAAAAAAAAaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa‌​aaaaaaaaAAAAAAA");` and got the same effect. This problem does not relate to your original question. I've got the same column width with different fonts in cell. The result may slightly change when you set different font in the first cell of column.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to close this question and open another one.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush

Comment: Here in 2023 it appears there's still an issue with autoResizeColumn(s) in a script versus manually double-clicking the column to force a resize. Super odd since I'd have to imagine a double-click to cause a resize utilizes the same exact underlying logic as the call in the script. Regardless, sharing here in case someone else needs a sanity check wrestling with it—you're not crazy.